# How would people react if hundreds of gods appeared in new york

Tags: society, magic, religion, gods

Tomorrow out of nowhere hundreds of naked humans appear in New York, they immediately announce themselves to whoever they encounter claiming to be  various gods from human mythologies and religions.  They willingly demonstrate their powers to anyone who questions them, many also request (in some cases demand) that people worship them and/or stop worshiping other gods. In the fist 24 hours how would politicians and world leaders respond? How would the media respond?

God powers:

Minor gods are usually connected to a peculiar place like a mountain or river. they can control that location but don't have any power outside of that.

Middle gods (think Zeus or Thor) can control or concept particular element like lightning, fire or warfare but are limited to their immediate area.

Major Gods (all knowing Gods) are capable of using their powers anywhere on Earth.

Comment: Are all the interpretations of the Abrahamic god going to appear?
I'm fairly sure there's black, female and neo-Nazi versions. What about satirical gods like the Pink Unicorn or Flying Spaghetti Monster? And the pantheons of D&D, Pathfinder, Warhammer, The Elder Scrolls. Kratos from the God of War games? The Elder Gods? Goku?

Comment: How would this be any different from a typical day in New York?

Comment: Your question is: "Something completely unprecedented and utterly extraordinary happens. May I please get a prediction of how people will react to that?". We cannot even predict what **song** is the next world hit (could you have predicted "Gangnam Style" would be YouTube's most watched, hm?) and now you want to know how humans react to something that is literally out of our known universe?! How do you expect this answer to be anything other than entirely fantasized by the answerer? Voted to close due to this.

Comment: Can humanity survive the ensuing wars between the gods?  Many pantheons were fairly violent, even internally (e.g., Greek mythology and the Trojan war), let alone against "outsider" gods.  I'm less concerned with how people are going to act, and more concerned with how these gods are going to react.

Comment: Seriously, opinion based? Isn't there a science SO for answers that *are not* opinion based?

Answer (score 3):

Some bright spark will go and find Thoth, and a few other knowledge gods, and ask them (a) what's really going on? (b) why here, and now? (c) Does [P = NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Trump campaigns on undocumented aliens coming to steal American jobs.   "What good is work as a hard American when some out of world deity comes and is willing to make gold rain from the sky for peanuts!"

Most people in Manhattan notice the gods arrived on a late Friday afternoon and spend the chaotic evening trying for sex.  After all, the gods will still be there on Monday.

Comment: It's a little short, but probably not wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Trump will build a wall to keep out those illegal immigrants.

Satan and the Spaghetti monster will go mad and call the apocalypse of pirate goats and raining meat balls.

The Four horsemen would probably organize an orgy, but without Pestilence cause ey smells like dead corpses.

Catholics and Christians will Ask god to whipe out all the demons  but God won't do anything cause it's plan is mysterious, So these believers will start another inquisition.

Some will start to pray the divine messenger Quetzalcoatl and sacrifice people in the name of God.

Egyptians will start doing autofellatio  to imitate their God RA...while Greek people will try to imitate Zeus by putting their penis inside everything.

If you want a serious answer say which gods and exactly how many cause there are about 1008 billion gods in over 5000 religions  and some new ones are created every day.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20630)

Comment: why this doesn't provide an answer to the question?  That exactly What would happen if gods existed...